# TimeSeries K-means clustering for multi-dimensional data

Tags: python, time-series, k-means

I'm using Tslearn's TimeSeriesKmeans library to cluster my dataset with shape (3000,300,8), However the documentation only talks about cases where the dimension of the dataset being (n_samples,timesteps,1)i.e (single feature). Can anybody help me understand if I can perform clustering with a higher dimension?
I'm using "DTW" as my distance metric.

Answer (score 1):

I used TimeSeriesKMeans from tslearn.clustering library. As you mentioned, the only example available on tslearn documentation is using 1 dimension input. However, it is very common to work with time series data with higher dimensions. For instance, in my case, I was clustering human motion which was 30 frames of 135 joint key points for each frame. Therefore, my data shape was like (number_of_samples, number_of_frames, features).

In order to use tslearns's Timeserieskmeans, you need to input an ndarray with (n_sample, m_time_step(sequence_length), k_features(k_dimensions) ).

If you take a look at the [documentations](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.html#tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.fit), fit function parameters is as follows:

> fit(X, y=None)[source] Compute k-means clustering.
>
> Parameters:    X : array-like of shape=(n_ts, sz, d) Time series
> dataset.
>
> y Ignored

The point is, your input data should be an ndarray with shape of (n_sample, seq_length, n_features) otherwise, it won't work. For example, at the first, my data was like a list of (n_samples,) and each element in that list was like (seq_length, features). It wan't work until I converted it to an ndarray with (n_sample, seq_length, features).